# iOS/iPadOS release version

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, ipados

I need to "release"(without uploading it to App Store) an app, but only for a single device. Can this be done without joining the Apple Developer Program? And without having the device connected or reconnected every fortnight.

Comment: Unfortunately no. To build and sign a release you will need a developer account and create an ad-hoc provisioning profile. Even then you would have to resign your app every year otherwise it would stop working.

Comment: Will it also stop working if the app is already downloaded, but I have not renewed my membership to the program?

Comment: Yes, it should stop working because if the provisioning profile expires, the app won't be signed, resulting in a crash at launch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You need to join the Apple Developer Program to release any app. When you sign up for the program, you can release the app as a custom app so that it can install app on devices you allow to learn more read here: [Distributing Custom Apps](https://developer.apple.com/custom-apps/)

Comment: What about the **release build version**, will that work forever on a device? Or will it too be unavailable in a short time as the **debug version**?

I can not seem to open your link, but it sounds like a good idea :)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I fixed the link! Yes, you can change the build versions how many times you want, but when you decide to release to the AppStore, you need to change the Build Version back to 1.0. If this was helpful, please mark the answer right!

Comment: I meant, the version I have to make before releasing it to App Store, will that version continue to work on the device, without me uploading the app?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Ok, so when you sign up for the program, your configuration profile is set to expire a year from the day you signed up, so yes, it will continue to work, but you will have to run the app once again with the new signing for it to work. You will not have to refresh the signing every "fortnight."

Comment: Okay, so it will only last longer if I join the program... Guess I will have to join

Comment: Yeah, it will only last longer by joining the program.